# Does Google Maps causes high live bytes?

Tags: ios, google-maps, instruments

I'm using Google Maps iOS SDK in my current application. The map view itself displays a lot of markers (about 900). I'm drawing the marker only with one image reference per marker already, however my live bytes in the application are extremly high (around 45MB).

I see in the instruments tool that `GLEngine` is most of the time the responsible library. The responsible caller are `allocateWCMemory` and `gleCreateVertexArrayHashObject`.

Answer (score 1):

4kb is the page size of buffer allocated by GLEngine. You may check whether you glDeleteBuffer when you do not need that buffer any more.